# Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]

Tags: haskell

I start learn Haskell. I'm trying run this code

```
-- Helpers.hs
module Helpers
where

lst1 +++ lst2 = if null lst1
            then lst2
            else (head lst1) : (tail lst1 +++ lst2)


reverse2 lst = if null lst
           then []
           else reverse2 (tail lst) : (head lst)
```

```
-- Main.hs
import Helpers

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . reverse2 [2, 8, 7]
```

I getting this error:

```
D:\Haskell\project>cabal configure
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring one-0.1.0.0...

D:\Haskell\project>cabal build
Building one-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'one' for one-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 2] Compiling Helpers          ( src\Utils\Helpers.hs, dist\build\one\one-t
mp\Helpers.o )

src\Utils\Helpers.hs:11:21:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]
    Relevant bindings include
      lst :: [[t]] (bound at src\Utils\Helpers.hs:9:10)
      reverse2 :: [[t]] -> [t] (bound at src\Utils\Helpers.hs:9:1)
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `reverse2 (tail lst)'
    In the expression: reverse2 (tail lst) : (head lst)
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: Since when have you been able to use a list of type `[[[[[[[[[[....[[[[[[a]]]]]]....]]]]]]]]]]`? That's the type `a ~ [a]` that you're describing

Comment: Also, it is very unidomatic and error prone to use null in the fashion. Pattern matching is far superior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the immediate problem is that you're passing arguments of the wrong type to the `:` operator, and haskell is trying to make them be the right type, and its struggle to get them to be the right type leads to obscure error messages.

As a general strategy, when weird error messages crop up like this, I start applying type signatures to the things it complains about so that haskell doesn't try to infer type signatures that are far away from what I intended.

Doing that with your code, I'd start by adding this to `reverse2`:

```
reverse2 :: [t] -> [t]
reverse2 lst = if null lst
           then []
           else reverse2 (tail lst) : (head lst)
```

This changes the error message to:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘t’ with actual type ‘[t]’
      ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for reverse2 :: [t] -> [t]
          at /tmp/flycheck-stackov.hs:6:13
    Relevant bindings include
      lst :: [t] (bound at /tmp/flycheck-stackov.hs:7:10)
      reverse2 :: [t] -> [t] (bound at /tmp/flycheck-stackov.hs:7:1)
    In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘reverse2 (tail lst)’
    In the expression: reverse2 (tail lst) : (head lst)
```

Okay, now it's saying "I expected type `t` but got type `[t]` when looking at the first argument to `:`".

And indeed, if we ask `ghci` what the type of `:` is, we see:

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So the left argument to `:` needs to be a single item, and the right argument a list. You're using a list on the left, and a single item on the right.

To concatenate the way you want, as the other answer says you should use `++`:

```
reverse2 :: [t] -> [t]
reverse2 lst = if null lst
           then []
           else reverse2 (tail lst) ++ [head lst]
```

(Also, you've got a type error in your `main` routine. You want to say `putStrLn $ reverse2 [2, 8, 7]` and not `putStrLn . reverse2 [2, 8, 7]`)

Comment: I think this is indeed the correct answer, but I'd consider adding the explanation @jwodder gave so this answer can be more complete. I'd also suggest adding the pattern matching strategy as an alternative to the ``if .. then ... else`` (without removing that implementation) since it's a more standard definition for this kind of functions.

Answer (score 9):

`reverse2 (tail lst)` is of type `[a]`, while `head lst` is type `a`.  Meanwhile, the `:` operator has type `a -> [a] -> [a]`.  When you try to do `reverse2 (tail lst) : (head lst)`, Haskell thinks that `head lst` is a list whose elements are the same type as `reverse2 (tail lst)` -- i.e., that `head lst :: [[a]]`.  However, `head lst` must also be the same type as the elements of `reverse2 (tail lst)`, which means `reverse2 (tail lst) :: [[[a]]]`, but then `head lst` has to be `[[[[a]]]]`, and then `reverse2 (tail lst)` has to be type `[[[[[a]]]]]`, and I think you can see where this is going.

This problem happens because you're using `:` incorrectly.  If you want to append an element to a list, the simplest way is `reverse2 (tail lst) ++ [head lst]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix it by:

```
reverse2 lst = if null lst
   then []
   else reverse2 (tail lst) ++ [head lst]
```

@jwodder already explained the more theoretical reasons this doesn't work.

Note that the above implementation is quite inefficient because `++` traverses its first argument completely and does concatenation afterwards.

A more sophisticated approach is the following

```
reverse3 lst = 
    let aux lst acc = if null lst then acc else aux (tail lst) (head lst : acc) 
    in aux lst []
```

It is often helpful to annotate types explicitly (i.e. you write `reverse2 :: [a] -> [a]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note expanding on what jwodder wrote, if you explicitly type things you can get a more helpful error message:

```
Prelude> let reverse2 :: [a] -> [a]; reverse2 lst = if null lst then [] else (reverse2 (tail lst)) : (head lst)

<interactive>:6:70:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[a]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for reverse2 :: [a] -> [a] at <interactive>:6:17
    Relevant bindings include
      lst :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:6:38)
      reverse2 :: [a] -> [a] (bound at <interactive>:6:29)
    In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(reverse2 (tail lst))’
    In the expression: (reverse2 (tail lst)) : (head lst)
```